# 'list' object has no attribute 'head'

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I need help with this programming code. So i was trying to sort the month of my data into number that represents the month (january = 1 and so on). When I try to apply a method to do that it gave me a TypeError : 'list' object has no attribute 'head'

```
import pandas as pd
import operator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

lod = pd.read_csv('LOD Project')
lod['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(lod['Date'])
lod['Month'] = lod['Date'].dt.month
lod_sort = sorted(lod, key=operator.itemgetter(3), reverse=True)
lod_sort.head()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-208-00698f1dbf18> in <module>
      1 lod_sort = sorted(lod, key=operator.itemgetter(3), reverse=True)
----> 2 lod_sort.head()

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'head'
```

[Data Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev905.png)

Comment: One challenge with pandas is to know when you are using a dataframe operator that applies to collections of dtypes in the dataframe and when you are just making python objects. For instance, dataframe abstracts "+" (plus) to work on the dataframe. But `sorted` just extracts data into python objects and sorts it into a list.

Comment: Alright, what is your question? What do/don't you understand from that error message? Also, please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `lod_sort = sorted(lod, key=operator.itemgetter(3), reverse=True)` returns a list, so whilst you've populated a pandas dataframe initially, when sorting it using this method, you are changing the returned type to a list.

Replace that line with a pandas dataframe sorting operation, something like:

```
lod_sort = lod.sort_values(by="Date", ascending=False)
```

Which will sort the data without changing the returned container type.

Answer (score 1):

I think `sorted` always return a list, and list doesn't have a `head` method. You can see the first n elements of a list with `list[:n]`

Answer (score 0):

*lod_sort * is a list not a dataframe, so lod.sort.head() doesn't work since .head() is a method of a dataframe.

sort the dataframe using df.sort() and you shouldn't have this problem.

```
lod_sort = lod.sort("date")
```

docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html

Comment: "sort" is deprecated (and not in my version of pandas) in favor of `sort_values`